# How to count number of times a character appears in a row

Tags: r, dataframe, counting

I have fairly simple question at a first glance but it has been bothering me for some time now.
I have data frame of different species and their growth on different substrates. (datased here is only a small section for illustration pourposes.

```
name <- c("Caal","cagl", "Capa")
f1 <- c("+","+","-")
f2 <- c ("-","-","+")
f3 <- c ("+","-","+")
df <- data.frame(name, f1,f2,f3)
```

Now I would like to count the number of times + is present in each row and write it in separate column.

Any hint would be really great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `rowSums`:

```
> rowSums(df == "+")
[1] 2 1 2
```

I'm assuming you know how to assign the output to a new column.